# If $|z_1 - z_2| = |z_1 + z_2|$, then $\arg z_1 - \arg z_2 = \pi/4 $

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

#### Problem

If $|z_1 - z_2| = |z_1 + z_2|$, show $$\arg(z_1) - \arg(z_2) = \frac{\pi}{4}.$$

#### Progress

I have tried squaring the modulus and using double angle formula for $\tan$, but can't get to the answer.

Comment: $\frac \pi 2$ maybe?

Comment: This isn't true. For example, let $z_1=1$ and $z_2=0$

Comment: It must be $\frac{\pi}{2}$. See my answer. Also, both numbers must be non zero for "arg" to be meaningful.

Comment: Zero doesn't have quite well-defined complex argument.

Comment: @sas Yes, my fault

Answer (score 5):

Geometric solution.

You have quadrilateral: two sides are your numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$, two diagonals are $r_1-r_2$ and $r_1+r_2$.

Diagonals are equal — so quadrilateral is rectangle.

Comment: Cool answer. Nicely done

Comment: Not as cool as it seems. I forgot to tell that it is not just a quadrilateral — it is parallelogram. Because it just represents vectors and translation. 
Other way it could be isosceles trapezium :)

Comment: That is just an oversight. The idea comes through.

Answer (score 3):

Assume both number are nonzero.

The condition is equivalent to
$$
(z_1-z_2)(\bar z_1 - \bar z_2)=(z_1+z_2)(\bar z_1 + \bar z_2)
$$
Multiply out to get
$$
\frac{z_1}{\bar z_1} = -\frac{z_2}{\bar z_2}
$$
or
$$
2 \angle z_1 = \pm\pi + 2 \angle z_2
$$
which gives
$$
\angle z_1 -\angle z_2 = \pm\frac{\pi}{2} 
$$