# If $|z_1 - z_2| = |z_1 + z_2|$, then $|\arg z_1 - \arg z_2 |= \frac{\pi}{2} $ or $\frac{3\pi}{2}$

Tags: complex-numbers

If for $z_1, z_2\in \Bbb C $, $|z_1 - z_2| = |z_1 + z_2|$, then we have to prove $|\arg z_1 - \arg z_2| = \frac{\pi}{2} $ or  $\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

I have seen similar type question here
[If $|z_1 - z_2| = |z_1 + z_2|$, then $\arg z_1 - \arg z_2 = \pi/4 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679130/if-z-1-z-2-z-1-z-2-then-arg-z-1-arg-z-2-pi-4?rq=1)
 But it is not clear to me how to show the result.

**Progress :**
$
|z_1 - z_2| = |z_1 + z_2| \\
  \Rightarrow|z_1 - z_2|^2 = |z_1 + z_2|^2 \\
  \Rightarrow (z_1-z_2)(\bar z_1 - \bar z_2)=(z_1+z_2)(\bar z_1 + \bar z_2) \\  
  \Rightarrow z_1\bar z_2=-\bar z_1 z_2
$

What to do now?

Comment: It might help to let $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ be two points in the complex plane and draw a diagram, illustrating the addition and subtraction of the complex numbers as vectors.

Comment: you assume but do not state that  $0 \neq z_1 \neq z_2 \neq 0$

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by $z_1 z_2$ to get $z_1^2 |z_2|^2 = - z_2^2 |z_1|^2$.

Let $w_1 = z_1/|z_1|$ and $w_2 = z_2/|z_2|$ so that both $w$'s have unit length, and $\arg w_i = \arg z_i$.

It follows that $w_1^2 = - w_2^2$, so that $w_1 = \pm i w_2$, implying $w_1$ and $w_2$ are orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

We may exploit the involutive property of a Cayley transform. Let $w=\frac{z_2}{z_1}$. We have:

$$\left|\frac{1-w}{1+w}\right|=1 $$
hence:
$$ \frac{1-w}{1+w}=e^{i\theta} $$
for some $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, from which $w = \frac{1-e^{i\theta}}{1+e^{i\theta}}$ or:

$$ w = \frac{e^{-i\theta/2}-e^{i\theta /2}}{e^{-i\theta/2}+e^{i\theta /2}} = -i\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right).$$
That implies $\arg w=\pm \arg i=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ and the claim follows.

Answer (score 0):

When $0\neq z_1 \neq z_2 \ne 0 $ ,  the points $ 0, z_1, z_2 , z_1+z_2$ are the vertices of a parallelogram  $P$in the complex plane.  Then $|z_1-z_2| =|z_1 +z_2|$ geometrically means that the diagonals of $P$ are of equal length, which implies that $P$ is a square.

Answer (score 0):

This question can be better viewed geometrically, but I will give you the solution from the step:
**$$\overline{z_{1}}z_{2}+z_{1}\overline{z_{2}}=0$$**
Now we know that this is nothing but :
**$$2Re({z_{1}\overline{z_{2}}})=0$$**
So the complex number ${z_{1}\overline{z_{2}}}$ is purely imaginary. When a complex number is purely imaginary the complex number is lying either on the positive or the negative imaginary axis on the Argand/Complex plane.
So the angle or the argument extended by the imaginary number ${z_{1}\overline{z_{2}}}$ is either $\pi/2$ or $3\pi/2$.
This means that :
**$$arg(z_{1}\overline{z_{2}}) = \pi/2 $$**
or 
**$$arg(z_{1}\overline{z_{2}}) = 3\pi/2$$**

Using the property, 
**$$arg(z_{1}\overline{z_{2}}) = arg(z1)+arg(\overline{z_{2}}) = arg(z_1) - arg(z_2)$$**
We get :
**$$ arg(z_1) - arg(z_2)= \pi/2 \,or\, 3\pi/2$$**

This same procedure has to be repeated for 
**$$2Re(\overline{z_{1}}z_2)=0$$** and you will get the same result with a negative sign that is :
**$$ arg(z_2) - arg(z_1)= \pi/2 \,or\, 3\pi/2$$**
So combining these two we get :
**$$|arg(z_1) - arg(z_2)|= \pi/2 \,or\, 3\pi/2$$**

I have not considered the principal argument so $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$ will do.